# GWT Gilead error

Tags: java, gwt, jpa, gilead

Well i have done all the setup for Gilead, although i get this error:

> [WARN] Exception while dispatching
>   incoming RPC call
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   net/sf/cglib/proxy/Enhancer   at
>   net.sf.beanlib.hibernate.UnEnhancer.unenhanceClass(UnEnhancer.java:65)
>     at
>   net.sf.gilead.core.hibernate.HibernateUtil.getUnenhancedClass(HibernateUtil.java:396)
>     at
>   net.sf.gilead.core.hibernate.HibernateUtil.isPersistentClass(HibernateUtil.java:365)
>     at
>   net.sf.gilead.core.PersistentBeanManager.mergePojo(PersistentBeanManager.java:463)
>     at
>   net.sf.gilead.core.PersistentBeanManager.merge(PersistentBeanManager.java:318)
>     at
>   net.sf.gilead.gwt.GileadRPCHelper.parseInputParameters(GileadRPCHelper.java:94)
>     at
>   net.sf.gilead.gwt.GileadRPCHelper.parseInputParameters(GileadRPCHelper.java:137)
>     at
>   net.sf.gilead.gwt.PersistentRemoteService.processCall(PersistentRemoteService.java:172)
>   ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the library "cglib-*.jar" in the execution classpath. You need to make the *runtime* dependencies for the modules

- adapter-core
- adapter4gwt
- hibernate-util

available to the server, as described in http://noon.gilead.free.fr/gilead/index.php?page=dependencies .

The usual way to do this, is to take the corresponding libraries - which are contained in your Gilead download (e.g. http://sourceforge.net/projects/gilead/files/gilead/1.3.2/), and your Hibernate download (e.g. http://sourceforge.net/projects/hibernate/files/hibernate3/3.6.3.Final/) - and put them into `war/WEB-INF/lib`.

Comment: Thank you, check my libraries please, aren't they enough? http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1035468/Picture%202.png. They are also included to my classpath

Comment: @kostas: No, it's a lot more libraries, e.g. you're missing "cglib-*.jar". You'll need all the dependencies I mentioned.

Comment: Where i can find the cglib.jars? I only found cglib-2.2.jar inside hibernate

Comment: Yes, I'd also use the cglib-2.2.jar from the hibernate distribution.

Comment: OK everything's fine, it worked! Thank you @Chris, without you i wouldn't have made it!